# Naming a German style beer

Tags: english-to-german, noun

I am the brewer at a small brewery and I am planning to brew a Berlinerweisse -style beer next. I want to call it "Trout Weisse", only in German. It is my understanding that the German word for "trout" is "Forelle". Would it make sense to name the beer "Forelleweisse"? or is it not that simple of a translation? I like the sound, the relevance, and the way the name looks phonetically; but I want to make sure it makes sense and that I'm not being offending anyone.

Thank you!

Comment: "Forellenweisse" would look more correct.

Comment: Why not "Weisse Forelle"? (_joke_)

Comment: I wonder how a beer named "Forellenweisse" would taste: Fishy?

Answer (score 2):

As far as *meaning* goes, that name is fine and unlikely to give offense.

*Euphonically* the translation is slightly inferior because of the additional syllables.

However, *morphologically* this would be abnormal. In compounds such as these you would normally employ the *Fugen-N*, so the name is "Forellenweisse".

And *orthographically*, the *ss* should actually be *ß*, but I'd be lying if I said that people care very much about the difference.

Comment: Should be "Forellenweiße" as it's a diphtong before the ß/ss. But "Forellen–Weiße" is more readable and easier to identify as related to *Berliner Weiße*

Comment: Some brewers of Berliner Weiße don't care either. I bet it's been "invented" by some ad agency who thought ß was "old-fashioned".